# How can I optimize this query and replace the MAX function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

```
SELECT MAX(f_orderInteractionID)                
FROM  tOrders O              
INNER JOIN tOrderInteractions  OI    ON OI.fk_orderID = O.f_orderID                
GROUP BY OI.fk_orderID
```

Is there a way to replace the max function because on the actual execution plan it uses Index scan and I prefer using an Index seek. How can I improve this query

Comment: Please edit the question to include table aliases for all the columns.

Comment: I would not be surprised with a scan rather than seek since there is no WHERE clause, but it depends on the cardinality of the joined columns.  Do you have any indexes on the columns inn the JOIN or GROUP BY clauses?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, try again

```
SELECT f_orderInteractionID
FROM  tOrders O              
INNER JOIN tOrderInteractions  OI    ON OI.fk_orderID = O.f_orderID
ORDER BY f_orderInteractionID DESC
LIMIT 1
```